# How do i run first function and then second function one by one in kotlin?

Tags: android, function, kotlin

how to call function in onCreate one by one? i want to run my first function first and after it finish it will run second function.

this is my code. everytime i click the button it keeps intent to the other activity on my saveData(). i want to my dataExist() run first until all the condition done and then it will run my saveData()

```
binding.btnContinue.setOnClickListener {
        dataExist()
        saveData()
    }
}
private fun saveData() {
    val pref = this.getSharedPreferences(Data.Preferences.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)

    val editor = pref.edit()
    editor.putString(Data.Preferences.PREF_FULLNAME, fullName)
    editor.putString(Data.Preferences.PREF_JOB, jobPref)
    editor.putString(Data.Preferences.PREF_EMAIL, emailPref)
    editor.putString(Data.Preferences.PREF_PASS, passPref)
    editor.apply()

    val intent = Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun dataExist() {
    val pref = this.getSharedPreferences(Data.Preferences.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)

    val prefName = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_FULLNAME, "")
    val prefJob = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_JOB, "")
    val prefEmail = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_EMAIL, "")
    val prefPass = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_PASS, "")

    if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_FULLNAME)) {
        if (fullName == prefName)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Name already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_JOB)) {
        if (job == prefJob)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Job already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_EMAIL)) {
        if (email == prefEmail)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_PASS)) {
        if (pass == prefPass)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pass already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, not sure what the probem is.

Comment: in my firstfunction i have a if else condition for my EditText, in my secondfunction i also have another if else condition for my dialog. when i try to run its keep running both at the same time

Comment: It really should run one after the other. It probably just happens so fasten that you think it's at the same time? Or do you mean that it should do the first on the first click and the second on the second click?

Comment: @IvoBeckers yes i mean that, if button clicked it should do the firstfunction first and then after all condition done it will run the secondfunction

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of the functions with the conditions?

Comment: I think you need to give more details. because with your code it really happens that the secondfunction happens after the firstfunction finishes

Comment: Do you want to call secondfunction from firstfunction based on some condition? See edited answer.

Comment: i already edit it. can you guys help me how to do that in my code?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your edit.

Comment: Your first function *does* finish - those "thing already exists" checks only display a ``Toast``, then the function runs to the end. And then the second function runs. If those checks are supposed to *prevent* the second function from running, they need to return a result that you can check, to see if you should run the second function or not. @MarioHuizinga 's answer does that - it checks the data, and tells you if it's ok to continue or not (it tells you if "data exists" which is the name of your function, it's like a question with an answer right?)

Answer (score 3):

Now we know your code, this is the way to do it: quit (return from) the function when there is a problem in a condition. Only when no problems found, you call the second function to save the data.

Edit: as Ivo pointed out, you can let dataExist() return a Boolean to make the code more readable:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding.btnContinue.setOnClickListener {
        if (!dataExist()) {
            saveData()
        }
    }    
}

private fun dataExist(): Boolean {
    val pref = this.getSharedPreferences(Data.Preferences.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)

    val prefName = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_FULLNAME, "")
    val prefJob = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_JOB, "")
    val prefEmail = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_EMAIL, "")
    val prefPass = pref.getString(Data.Preferences.PREF_PASS, "")

    if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_FULLNAME)) {
        if (fullName == prefName) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Name already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
    }
    if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_JOB)) {
        if (job == prefJob) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Job already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
    }
    if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_EMAIL)) {
        if (email == prefEmail) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
    }
    if (pref.contains(Data.Preferences.PREF_PASS)) {
        if (pass == prefPass) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pass already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Personally I would not call `saveData()` inside `dataExist()`. It sort of violates `dataExist()`'s responsibility. I would let `dataExist()` return a boolean with whether all checks are passed and then do `if (dataExist()) saveData()` in the click listener. But of course, functionally your solution works too

Comment: Good point @IvoBeckers. I have adopted your suggestion.

Comment: @Vin If this is the answer that helped you, you can 'accept' the answer by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons. That also prevents your question showing up in the list of questions without an accepted answer.